# Comparing Data in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have searched but cannot find an answer that suits my needs specifically. I have two sets of data and need to compare a piece of the first (table 1 Description field) with a list (table two) and return the VIP codes for each interface/order.

The only identifier that is the same for any of the descriptions is the 9 digit order ID that ends in '003'. I need to compare this 9 digit string to the other table that will always start with the order ID but may contain other characters or numbers afterwards. I know a LIKE comparison will work for the second table but I cannot figure out how to strip the order numbers out of the description field.

UPDATE: Table 1 is a temporary table comparing the output of a router interface command. Table 2 is my static account database that has tens of thousands of entries that I do not want to compare to table one. This is why I do not just take table two and compare the order numbers to table one. I am specifically asking for help with a way to extract the 9 digit order ID from the description field of Table 1.

**Table 1**

```
Interface    Description
Ge 1/0/1     blah_bla_123456003_blahlahlah
Ge 1/0/2     blah_blah_bla_234567003_blahahblh
Ge 1/0/3     b_bla_345678003_blhahblah
Ge 1/0/4     bh_blh_ba_456789003_lahlahbl
```

**Table 2**

```
Order ID       VIP Code
123456003.0    Premier
234567003      Wholesale
345678003.6    Normal
456789003.23   Premier
```

**Expected Results**

```
Order*        VIP Code
123456003     Premier
234567003     Wholesale
345678003     Normal
456789003     Premier

*(stripped from Description)
```

Comment: That is really a problematic database schema.  If yo need to join these tables, you should make something readily available for them to do so (an autoincrementing primary key perhaps).

Comment: How hard is it to look at the list of string functions in the MySQL documentation and find the ones that get you the first 9 characters of a column? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

Comment: I need to compare Table 1 to Table 2. I already know how to get the leftmost 9 characters from table two, however table two in reality is tens of thousands of entries and I would rather not bash that whole list against Table 1 that is 50-100 entries. this is why I am asking for a way to pull the needed 9 character string from description field in table one instead of just bashing the thousands of entries from table two against table 1 with a like query.

Comment: What else is in the Description field of Table1?  Is it full of numbers or just letters.  If you know what is in there we may be able to filter out just the order number.

Comment: Unfortunately there may be other numbers, letters, and underscores. It is EXREMELY unlikely that any of the other information in the descriptions will be 9 digits and end in the numbers '003' however so if there is a way to extract anything that can fit digit only '######003' that would be what I need.

Comment: Also the nine digits for the order number may have underscores, spaces, or dashes on either side of them. The people who provisioned my routers do not have a standard naming convention unfortunately.

Comment: You are not going to get this fast because off the problematic database schema. even if you index Description and OrderId two full table scans are needed  100 * 10000 = 1000000 rows

Comment: Doing a bit more research perhaps something can be done using locate() and mid() to extract the 9 digit number ending in 003 then compare it to table 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the first 9 digits of ID from Table 2, you could use `left(table2.id,9)`. It will return the 9 first (left) characters from that field.

Then you can use that with a LIKE (using the "***%***" wildcard) or using regular expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately Table 2 in reality is tens of thousands of entries. Table 1 is a hundred or so interfaces dumped from my router. So it would be extremely inconvenient to go from table 2 to table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the data you need in a dedicated column in each table? Make it a number column and index it, then you can do a very efficient `JOIN` using that column.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1 LEFT JOIN Table_2 USING(common_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you something like this :

```
select TRUNCATE(tbl2.orderId,0) orderNum, tbl2.vipcode, tbl1.interface
from table2 tbl2 , table1 tbl1
WHERE tbl1.description like CONCAT('%',TRUNCATE(tbl2.orderId,0),'%');
```

i made a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3fbc/10)